# Azure Devops Pull Request and Jenkins behind corporate network

Tags: azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to figure out how can I connect my Jenkins Build server to the Azure DevOps Pull Request.  My Jenkins Server is behind a corporate firewall, I don't have any way to have access to this server outside of the corporate network.

Due to the corporate network rules I cannot add a hook in Azure to call my Jenkins server, but my server can have access to the Microsoft Azure web site.

I tried to run the VSTS Agent with success on my Linux Jenkins server.  It works, but It doesn't do what I would need to do.  I don't want to change all my build process to build my application inside this Agent. I really want to be able to launch a Jenkins Pipeline build from my server and forward the build result to the Azure DevOps.

I cannot use the Jenkins VM provided by Azure DevOps, because my Jenkins build process has to run some regression test tool on real hardware unit in our lab to flag the build as a success.

So in other word:

1- I cannot use the VSTS agent because I need to use my Jenkins Build Server

2- I cannot use the Jenkins VM provided by Azure DevOps because I need to have access to real Hardware Unite

3- I think I cannot instrument  my Jenkins to see if we have a new Pull Request branch, because I will not be able to send the Jenkins build result to the Microsoft Azure DeveOps server.

Anybody had to do something like that?

Any reading to suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since one-way communication is going to be possible (from Jenkins to Azure DevOps), you'll have to do the following:

- Set up your Jenkins pipeline to periodically poll Azure DevOps for new PR branches and build PRs
- Set up a branch policy for [approval from external services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#require-approval-from-external-services)
- Have Jenkins post the build status back to the external service API so that Azure DevOps knows whether the build has succeeded or failed

Comment: Daniel, can you elaborate on bullet 1?  I am using a multi-branch plugin, triggered off of a webhook, but it builds the source branch and the master branch individually, but not the merge result, which is what people really need to see. (I realize the merge hasn't happened yet, but reviewers need to know that it will build and test when it does.)  is there a different Jenkins plugin that would do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full solution, but a partial one if you haven't figured this out yet Stephane, more on it at the end. But the general idea for those situations is to use the exposed Azure Devops REST API from your corporate Jenkins to update specific statuses on commits/PRs. (as Daniel wrote in his answer)

Assumptions:

- you have credentials defined for http calls named 'azure'
- organization and projectName can be probably hard coded
- you can find your azureRepositoryId from the Azure API as well, just list the repositories

Documentation from Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
import groovy.json.JsonOutput


@NonCPS
def retrievePrIds(content) {
    def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
    return json.value.collect{it.pullRequestId}
}

def notifyAzure(repositoryId, status, desc) {
    def azureQueryUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${projectName}/_apis/git/pullrequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs%2Fheads%2F${env.BRANCH_NAME.replaceAll('\\/','%2F')}&searchCriteria.sourceRepositoryId=${repositoryId}&searchCriteria.status=active&searchCriteria.repositoryId=${repositoryId}&api-version=5.1"
    
    try {
        def res = httpRequest authentication: 'azure', timeout: 5, url: azureQueryUrl
        
        echo "${res.content}"

        def prIds = retrievePrIds(res.content)

        for (prId in prIds) {
            echo "${prId}"
            def azurePRUdateUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${projectName}/_apis/git/repositories/${repositoryId}/pullRequests/${prId}/statuses?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
            def json = JsonOutput.toJson([state: status, description: desc, targetUrl: env.BUILD_URL, context: [name: 'jenkins build', genre: 'continuous-integration']])
            
            httpRequest authentication: 'azure', contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'POST', requestBody: json, responseHandle: 'NONE', timeout: 5, url: azurePRUdateUrl 
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        echo "Error: Failed to update azure PR status, cause: ${e.getCause()}"
    }
    
    notifyAzureCommit(repositoryId, status, desc)
}

def notifyAzureCommit(repositoryId, status, desc) {
    def azureUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${projectName}/_apis/git/repositories/${repositoryId}/commits/${env.GIT_COMMIT}/statuses?api-version=5.1"
    def json = JsonOutput.toJson([state: status, description: desc, targetUrl: env.BUILD_URL, context: [name: 'jenkins build', genre: 'continuous-integration']])
    try {
        httpRequest authentication: 'azure', contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'POST', requestBody: json, responseHandle: 'NONE', timeout: 5, url: azureUrl 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        echo "Error: Failed to update azure commit status, cause: ${e.getCause()}"
    }
}
```

Then use it at beginning of the stages

```
notifyAzure(azureRepositoryId, 'pending', 'Job started') //last one could be the stage name
```

and in post actions

```
post{
    success {
        notifyAzure(azureRepositoryId, 'succeeded', 'Job successful')
    }
    failure {
        notifyAzure(azureRepositoryId, 'failed', 'Job failed')
    }
    unstable {
        notifyAzure(azureRepositoryId, 'error', 'Job unstable')
    }
}
```

In azure policies for your branch you might now have a status check and this will guard your PRs for sure:

[image]

There's a gap though, in this code there's a hack to find the active PRs to source branch being built. Which is not correct from the point of view of the PR itself. Reason for that is azure does regular branches under git refspec `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` and the clean PR branches without an topic branch needed under `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/`, which my Jenkins instance has trouble checking out.

So a complete solution should actually have a build for PRs in Jenkins going for `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/` refspec and having the API called based on the current branch name (as it contains the PR number in it) so you can call the Azure Devops REST API with it. No need to update the commit status for those. And then a regular build for non PR branches that update commit statuses.

If I'll manage to make my jenkins build those I'll update this answer.

After further research it seems not to be supported for multibranch pipelines, there's an open bug for it [here](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-59392) and [here](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64719).

EDIT:
I'm able to create a multi-branch pipeline for pull requests with the following:

- discover other refs: `pull/*/merge`
- specify ref spec: `+refs/pull/*/merge:refs/pull/*/merge`

I would say with use of it the approach should be complete.